# "message": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addcategory'",

Tags: django

## this is my views .py (trying to get data in postman)

def list(self,request):

```
    try:
        user=sub_category.objects.all()
        users=[]
        for i in user:
            users.append({
                'category':i.category,
                'subcategory':i.subcategory
            })
        return Response({'data':users})
        print('hello',subcategory)
    except Exception as error:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return Response({"message": str(error), "success": False}, 
        status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

## this is my models

class add_category(models.Model):

```
addcategory=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.addcategory
```

class sub_category(models.Model):

```
category=models.ForeignKey('add_category',
on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True,related_name='xyz')
subcategory=models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True,blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.subcategory
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error ?

Comment: "message": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'addcategory'"

Comment: i am hitting list(get) in postman

Comment: can you help me in this?

Comment: problem has been solved

Comment: for i in user:
            users.append({
                'category':i.category.addcategory,
                'subcategory':i.subcategory
            })